# Stroke-dasharray tween on multiple paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js, interpolation, tween

I am projecting multiple line paths on a map and hoping to use [stroke-dash interpolation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592) on them to show path movements.

I want to use the same Tween function on all the paths, but it seems as though the Tween is returning the same value for every path. All of the lines seem to be projecting fine; it's only the Tween that's causing some issue.

It causes this issue, where the paths show stroke-dashes:

[image]

It should instead look like the following:

[image]

My lines are projected using the following standard process for a leaflet x/y conversion:

```
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");

var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");
var transform = d3.geo.transform({
            point: projectPoint
        });
    var d3path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

    var toLine = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function(d,i) {
            return applyLatLngToLayer(d).x
        })
        .y(function(d,i) {
            return applyLatLngToLayer(d).y
        });

    g.selectAll(".lineConnect").remove();

    var linePath = g.selectAll(".lineConnect")
        .data(series)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "lineConnect")

        linePath.attr("d", toLine)
```

And here you see the function that calls the Tween:

```
 function transition() {
            linePath.transition()
                .duration(700).attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash);     
 } 
 function tweenDash() {
            return function(t) {
                var l = linePath.node().getTotalLength(); 
                interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
                return interpolate(t);
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that you have only a single element in the selection (`linePath.node()`) -- you're getting the length of the first element only. You could use for example `.each()` to make it work for every line:

```
function transition() {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(700).attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash);     
 } 
 function tweenDash() {
        var that = this;
        return function(t) {
            var l = that.getTotalLength(); 
            interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
            return interpolate(t);
        }
 }

 linePath.each(transition);
```

Comment: I tried using .each(d3.select(this).attrTween("stroke-dasharray",tweenDash); but it didin't work.. will try your solution.

Comment: The this in the tweenDash function is referring to the window.

Comment: Ah right, nested functions... I've edited the answer.

Comment: It worked. You are a badass, sir. A side question: How do you think the performance compares between tweening between two points and using an x, y line transition between them?

Comment: Hmm, don't know off the top of my head -- I would benchmark for the individual case. My gut feeling is that this would only become an issue once there are way too many transitions going on for humans to make sense of the whole thing.

Comment: I am at 320 transitions :) Any guess? It works much faster with the above modification btw.

Comment: Well if it's not too slow at the moment I certainly wouldn't change it :)

Comment: Well I guess the only way to find out is to implement the other method and see. But 320 is quite a lot, so I wouldn't expect any massive performance improvements.